# Less.NET Variables Not Working

Tags: .net, less

I have a medium size stylesheet.  I've incorporated less, and everything downloads fine.  However, wherever a variable is defined, nothing is output.  Check the sample below:

```
@baseFontSize: 10pt;
@borderColor: #2E6E9E;

/****** .less version ******/
body
{
    font-size: @baseFontSize;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    color: #222222;
    background-color: #fff;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

All of the styles for the body are there, except for `font-size`, as shown by firebug:

```
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #222222;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure it's compiling? I don't see border color referenced in the style output either

Comment: The body is in the .less file; I added firebug's output.  border is used down later on, not in code snippet.

Comment: what if you use px instead of pt?

Comment: I made the variable @baseFontSize: 20px; to no avail...

Comment: did you tried to use `$baseFontSize` (`$` sign instead of `@`), just to see if you get stuff going on? if yes, they it's been set for SCSS and not Less, if not, there is must be a problem in the config or library, I suggest that you donload and install it from **nuget**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with IIS 7: http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2010/05/fix-dotless-for-iis-7-with-integrated.html

I was missing the handlers section in system.webserver.